# check if process is running VBS, when closed log off

Tags: vbscript

Apologies i am a bit of a newbie at vbs and was wondering if i could get some help.

I want to write some vbscript to check if a process name is still running, if it is keep checking the process. If the process-name is not running log off windows.

This is what i have tried so far

```
set service = GetObject ("winmgmts:")

for each Process in Service.InstancesOf ("Win32_Process")
    If Process.Name = "notepad.exe" False ,then

Set WshShell=WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    WshShell.run "shutdown.exe -L -F" 
    'wscript.echo "Notepad running"
    'wscript.quit
End If
next
```

please let me know if you need any more information :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This vbscript can did the trick :

```
Option Explicit
Dim ProcessPath,WshShell
ProcessPath = "%Windir%\System32\Notepad.exe"
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
If AppPrevInstance() Then 
    MsgBox "There is an existing proceeding !" & VbCrLF &_
    CommandLineLike(WScript.ScriptName),VbExclamation,"There is an existing proceeding !"    
    WScript.Quit   
Else 
    Do
        Pause(10) ' Pause 10 seconds 
        If CheckProcess(DblQuote(ProcessPath)) = False Then
            Call Logoff() 
        End If  
    Loop
End If
'**************************************************************************
Function CheckProcess(ProcessPath)
    Dim strComputer,objWMIService,colProcesses,Tab,ProcessName
    strComputer = "."
    Tab = Split(ProcessPath,"\")
    ProcessName = Tab(UBound(Tab))
    ProcessName = Replace(ProcessName,Chr(34),"")
    Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
    & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
    Set colProcesses = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
    ("Select * from Win32_Process Where Name = '"& ProcessName & "'")
    If colProcesses.Count = 0 Then
        CheckProcess = False
    Else
        CheckProcess = True
    End if
End Function
'**************************************************************************
Function DblQuote(Str)
    DblQuote = Chr(34) & Str & Chr(34)
End Function
'**************************************************************************
Sub Logoff()
    Dim ws,Command,Execution
    Set ws = CreateObject("wscript.Shell")
    Command = "Cmd /c shutdown.exe -L -F"
    Execution = ws.run(Command,0,True)
End sub
'**************************************************************************
Sub Pause(Secs)    
    Wscript.Sleep(Secs * 1000)    
End Sub   
'**************************************************************************
Function AppPrevInstance()   
    With GetObject("winmgmts:" & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\cimv2")   
        With .ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE CommandLine LIKE " & CommandLineLike(WScript.ScriptFullName) & _
            " AND CommandLine LIKE '%WScript%' OR CommandLine LIKE '%cscript%'")   
            AppPrevInstance = (.Count > 1)   
        End With   
    End With   
End Function    
'***************************************************************************
Function CommandLineLike(ProcessPath)   
    ProcessPath = Replace(ProcessPath, "\", "\\")   
    CommandLineLike = "'%" & ProcessPath & "%'"   
End Function
'****************************************************************************
```